# The .net core mvc is reaching the json controller I POST, but I can't read it. I also get error code 415 when I use [FromBody]

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm posting a data with XHR in the project I'm coding. A JSON reaches the Controller but if I use `[FromBody]` I get `error code 415`. If I don't use it, the incoming JSON looks empty.

##### Controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[Route("revizedCategoryzfc")]
public void revizedCategoryzfc([FromBody] Category model) 
{
    if (model.fileCode != null)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(model.fileCode);
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("Girdi");
}
```

##### Post XHR Code

```js
async function makeRequest(method, url, model) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            }else {
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
            }
        };

        xhr.onerror = function() {
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        };

        xhr.send(model);
    });
}

document.querySelector('.save-service').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    for (var es of document.querySelectorAll('.category-item'))
    {
        await makeRequest('POST', '/zfc/revizedCategoryzfc', JSON.stringify({
            "Name": es.querySelector('.service-name').value,
            "fileCode": es.querySelector('.filecodas').value,
            "CategoryId": es.querySelector('.zfc-id').value
        }))
    }
})
```

##### Error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you user json strngify and frombody, you have to add this header to your xhr

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: When I added this, the data was returning empty. I will try again. Thank you. I accepted the answer.

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: @i3kafa You are welcome, Try to check a model values. Try alert(model);  before sending request.